# Button is not showing up in WPF Grid

Tags: wpf

I have a Grid inside of a Grid but when i try to display a button with text, it doesn't show up.

My WPF has a Grid nested inside of a parent Grid.

```
<Grid Margin="124,0,0,225">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="Test" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

                <TextBox  Width="400" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"  FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Center" KeyDown="HandleEnterKey"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Text="Enter Amount" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBox  Width="250" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3"  FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Center" KeyDown="HandleEnterKey"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="5" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Grid
            x:Name="chilGrid"
            Width="auto"
            Height="auto"
            Background="Black"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.Row="7">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Button Margin="10, 10, 5, 5" Grid.Column="0" Content="test" Grid.Row="0" Background="Pink" 
BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="10">
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
```

Edit# 1:
Modified the button section to this:

```
<Button Grid.Column="0" Content="test" Grid.Row="0" Background="Pink" 
    BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                        </Button>
```

Still did not work?

`The 'Test' button is not showing up inside the nested Grid?

Comment: Ensure it has enough height (or set `.Padding` to `0`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button resides in below grid and it has several values that affect the visibility, like border thickness, margin etc. You can use stackpanel or even simply your existing grid. You don't need column for main grid (for example).

Try below code.

```
 <Grid Margin="124,0,0,225">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Test" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBox  Width="400" Grid.Row="1"  FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Center" KeyDown="HandleEnterKey"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="Enter Amount" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBox  Width="250" Grid.Row="3"  FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Center" KeyDown="HandleEnterKey"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="5" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Grid
            x:Name="chilGrid"
            Width="auto"
            Height="auto"
            Background="Black"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.Row="7">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="test" Background="Pink" 
BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
            </Button>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

and you get something like below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's there, but the combination of your margins, and border thickness means it blends in with the black background of the grid.

Make your border thickness 1, and remove the margin and you will see the button.

Comment: Hi I modified the code but still nothing showed up? Did i do that correctly?

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Remove the margin off the first grid too.